Packmol messing up the ligand bonds
I use Packmol to solvate my protein in a solvent and have a ligand in the protein file. The issue is that after solvation, the ligand bonds are changed and here you can see the result:

The protein: https://www.rcsb.org/structure/8PGW
I use solvate.tcl for packing:
./solvate.tcl 8pgw.pdb
Here is the generated input file:
tolerance 2.0
filetype pdb
output solvated.pdb

structure ../8pgw.pdb
  number 1
  center
  fixed 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
end structure

structure WATER.pdb
  number   12675
  inside box -36.8195 -38.476 -38.4905 36.8195 38.476 38.4905
end structure


structure SODIUM.pdb
  number       37
  inside box -36.8195 -38.476 -38.4905 36.8195 38.476 38.4905
end structure


structure CHLORIDE.pdb
  number 7
  inside box -36.8195 -38.476 -38.4905 36.8195 38.476 38.4905
end structure

which I run with:
./packmol < packmol_input.inp
--
input file: https://files.rcsb.org/download/8PGW.pdb
output file that I get: link

I checked the 8pgw.pdb first, and it seems fine except for the ligand, where VMD recognizes the bond between the ligand and the zinc ion as a bond. But I do not see the messed up bonds as you see. Can you share the other PDB files to replicate this issue again.

@Vasista The original PDB file is fine. The weird bonds happen after packing.

is it possible to share the other pdb files to replicate this issue?

@Vasista I shared my input and outputs.

The issue is the CONECT records, when you download the pdb from the RCSB, it by default, contains CONECT records (bond information), and the CONECT records essentially contains the indices of the atoms. I guess the PACKMOl is readjusting the indices number which messes up the bonding information and causing these weird bonds. I removed the CONECT records manually and when I load in VMD, I do not see any weird bonds. I suggest doing a small post-processing step after you download, before packing using PACKMOL.

The issue lies with the CONECT records in the PDB file. When you download a PDB file from the RCSB, it includes CONECT records (bond information based on atom indices). PACKMOL appears to be readjusting these atom indices, essentially changing this bonding info, resulting in incorrect bonds. I manually removed the CONECT records and loaded the file in VMD, and I no longer saw the weird bonds. I recommend performing a small post-processing step to remove the CONECT records from your PDB file before using PACKMOL.
You can download the file here.
